# How to set up IMAP/POP account manually (skip "Simplified Account Creation") in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-outlook-2019

I want to add Google Mail's IMAP or POP account to Outlook 2016 for Mac.
However Outlook always tries to log in via a browser in all cases. Even if I choose "Not Gmail" option and select "IMAP/POP" provider.

How to skip this "Simplified Account Creation" option and manually set up IMAP account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## For Windows

There is an [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3189194/how-to-disable-simplified-account-creation-in-outlook) from Microsoft Support which describes how to disable "Simplified Account Creation" via a registry:

> 1. Exit Outlook.
> 2. Start Registry Editor. To do this, use one of the following procedures, as appropriate for your version of Windows.
>
>    - Windows 10, Windows 8.1 and Windows 8: Press Windows Key + R to open the Run dialog box. Type regedit.exe, and then click OK.
>    - Windows 7: Click Start, type regedit.exe in the search box, and then press Enter.
> 3. In Registry Editor, locate and then click the user settings subkey in the registry:
>      `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\setup`
>
>    or the group policy subkey in the registry:
>      `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\setup`
> 4. Point to New on the Edit menu and then DWORD (32-bit) Value.
> 5. Type `DisableOffice365SimplifiedAccountCreation`, and then press Enter.
> 6. Right-click `DisableOffice365SimplifiedAccountCreation`, and then select Modify.
> 7. In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
> 8. On the File menu, select Exit to exit Registry Editor.

For more details please check the [original article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3189194/how-to-disable-simplified-account-creation-in-outlook).

## For Mac

I accidentally found an unexpected and easy way to add a custom IMAP/POP account:

1. Open Outlook Preferences
2. Hold `Option` key and click on "Accounts" in "Personal Settings" section.
3. Click on "Add" button (`+` icon) in the bottom of the account list. Now there are new actions:

   - New account...
   - **Exchange...**
   - **Outlook.com...**
   - **Other Email...**
   - Directory Service...
4. Select "Other Email" option.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, and kudos on solving your problem.  Your own problem was on a Mac, and the question and answer focus there.  However, you thoughtfully provided some help for Windows users.  Microsoft Support articles have a habit of disappearing, in which case, that helpful link would just be a tease.  As long as you found it, consider adding the critical elements of it to the answer, and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Since it's just a helpful addition, it could go at the end.  (cont'd)

Comment: And since the thread supports both Mac and Windows users, you could remove the Mac reference in the question title so Windows readers with the same problem won't be discouraged from looking here for a solution.  Just some thoughts.  :-)  BTW, in 2 days you'll be able to accept your own answer.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! Edited the question and the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1391960/how-to-enter-username-of-imap-account-in-outlook-2016/1391985#1391985) suggests on Outlook for Windows, using the Mail control panel accessed through File > Account Settings > Manage Profiles.

Answer (score 0):

reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\setup /T REG_DWORD /F /V DisableOffice365SimplifiedAccountCreation /D 1

reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\setup

Comment: Please expand on the exact steps your are suggesting the OP take. The `reg` commands are not clear on their own (without the context of the other answers provided).